# Como trabajar con reporting services sin ingresar todas las máquinas en un dominio

Tags: ssrs

Ya trabajo algún tiempo utilizando reporting services, pero algo que no logro hacer es que trabaje en red sin que ingrese todos los equipos en un dominio, por lo que leí es un problema del tipo de seguridad que utiliza por defecto Reporting Services, lo que no logre entender como se debe configurar esta herramienta para que trabaje en red sin necesidad de que los equipos estén en un dominio. Si alguien podría ayudarme con este problema le agradecería mucho.

Saludos

Néstor Umboni

Comment: Hola nestor, bienvenido a la comunidad, para que conozcas como usar el sitio haz el [tour de inicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), ¿Obtienes algún error al realizar lo que indicas o que es lo que sucede exactamente?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que si tengo que instalar el sistema por decir entre 2 maquinas una necesito instalarle el Windows 2008 Server, por ejemplo, configurar el dominio, ingresar el otro equipo al dominio crear usuarios para el active directory, darle acceso y roles a estos usuarios en el   Reporting Services y recien puede acceder la máquina cliente a los reportes, entonces yo se que existe  un modo en el cual no hay necesidad de todo esto pero no se como configurarlo y menos acceder a esta configuración

Comment: Lo que sucede es que la forma de trabajar en red para que otros usuarios puedan acceder a los reportes es: Instalo en el equipo servidor un Sistema Operativo Servidor, configuro el dominio y el Active Directory, creo los usuarios, luego instalo el sql server y el reporting services, le doy acceso mediante roles a los usuarios del dominio y recién pueden acceder a los reportes. Se que hay un modo en el cual no haya necesidad de que los usuarios pertenezcan a un Dominio para darles acceso a los reportes